# For How Long Time Can My App Have Access?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I need to create an app which can post photos on behalf of the user to his/her wall or photoalbum. What is the longest possible time the app can post photos without the user actually visiting/using the app personally at Facebook.

Answer (score 1):

About 60 Days if you request a long-lived access token. See here for details: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/

Comment: I was afraid you would say that. Can I use an App Access Token instead of the User Token?

Comment: If you're posting on a user's behalf, no. You need a user access token to do that. You can use an app access token as a permanent means to pull some public data using the Facebook API.